# Rails, Jasmine-headless: Specs only run inside guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine, guard, jasmine-headless-webkit

I'm trying to set up a rails/backbone/jasmine suite, and I'm having a problem getting jasmine-headless-webkit to run.

If I run the jasmine suite via guard, it passes, but if I run jasmine-headless-webkit from console, I get:

> 2013-01-01 10:06:22.855 jasmine-webkit-specrunner[1809:707] ***
>   WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on
>   10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead.  SyntaxError: Parse error
>
> Test ordering seed: --seed 5430

And no tests run.

Just to clarify, the jasmine suite not only loads, but passes via Guard...but no joy at all in jasmine-headless-webkit. Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but if anyone is still looking for the best way to run Jasmine tests headless, look into the Snapdragon project, available here: https://github.com/reachlocal/snapdragon